# Swift IQkeyboard manager . Code doesnt work in the simulator. Keyboard doesnt pop up at all when the text field is pressed

Tags: swift, xcode

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
    
    
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
        print(db)
    
   
    
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to IOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard and toggle "toggle software keyboard" or command k.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but, it only pops up when i press command K and not when i actually want it to pop up when i click the text field in the simulator. any views on this issue please?

Comment: For me I just do IOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard and toggle "toggle software keyboard" and click, it tends to shut off when you use command k, or have a keyboard plugged in.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped.